# How to make IN condition check for set values

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Basically I have two tables

```
MY_CHARACTER:
 _________________________________________________
| char_ID |   char_name | char_class | char_rank |
|------------------------------------------------|
|    1    |   Aragorn   |  Fighter   |     99    |
|    2    |   Legolas   |  Archer    |     90    |
|    3    |   Smeagle   |  Spy       |     20    |
|________________________________________________|
```

and

```
EQUIPMENT:
     _________________________________________________
    | equip_ID | equip_name  | equip_owner | required  |
    |--------------------------------------------------|
    |    1    | The one ring |     3       |     99    |
    |    2    | Longsword    |     1       |     90    |
    |    3    | Waistcloth   |     3       |     10    |
    |    4    | Nazguls Mask |     2       |     95    |
    |__________________________________________________|
```

Now what I want is to make a select command using IN condition, which will give me list of equipments that the characters are not eligible to use. So in this very example, it would be Smeagle being ineligible to wear the one ring and Legolas unable to wield the nazguls mask.

My command looks something like this

```
SELECT equip_name, equip_owner, required
FROM EQUIPMENT WHERE required IN (SELECT char_rank MY_CHARACTER);
```

Now this will only print out the equipment where required=char_rank however i want to print out a select, where required equipment level is higher than char_rank instead. Any idea how? Ideally using the IN condition.

**EDIT**: To clear out confusion regarding where I want, basically what my command does right now is it checks if `EQUIPMENT.required=MY_CHARACTER.char_rank` what I want instead is that it checks `EQUIPMENT.required>MY_CHARACTER.char_rank`

Comment: Higher than which `char_rank`

Comment: what do you meand with  "required equipment level is higher than char_rank instead" ???

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a `join`:

```
select c.*, equip_id as notEligible
from my_character c join
     equipment e 
     on c.char_rank < e.required;
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want a list of items, that a certain character is not allowed to use you can slightly modify your SQL:

```
SELECT 
  equip_name, equip_owner, required
FROM 
  EQUIPMENT 
WHERE 
  required > (SELECT char_rank FROM MY_CHARACTER WHERE char_id=?);
```